# react suspense - Is it normal to have two renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, react-suspense

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-suspense-forked-2fq784?file=/src/index.tsx)

In the code example above, the console is detected twice when data is loaded into the Gender component. Is this normal?

Comment: Put the console.log inside the useEffect  **React.useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("rendering");
},[]);** and 
  **React.useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("data", data);
},[data]);**